# Из-за созданного мной request'а выскакивает ошибка "The GET/POST method is not supported for this route"

Tags: php, laravel

В файле web.php при использовании метода Route::post, при обработке url, который связан с данным методом, вот такая ошибка:

> "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST."

При использовании Route::get такая:

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD."

Почему при использовании метода Route::get, у меня вылазит ошибка о том, что нельзя использовать метод POST? Это как-то странно...

```
Route::post('/personalOffice/changePassword', [ChangePasswordController::class, 'changePassword']);
```

- вот так выглядит мой метод. Вместо ChangePasswordController я мог использовать любой другой контроллер(как и метод),даже тот, который уже применялся, это ни на что не влияет.

В контроллере у меня есть метод changePassword:

```
   public function changePassword(ChangePasswordRequest $request)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
```

Если в параметрах метода использовать Request вместо ChangePasswordRequest, то у меня всё заработает(вернётся разметка файла welcome.blade.php). Однако, мне нужно использовать именно свой Request. И что бы я там не написал, даже если там - самая простая валидация:

```
        return [
            'newPassword' => ['required', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
        ];
```

Всё равно будет та же самая проблема...

Если что, то вот код формы

```
<form method="post" action="personalOffice/changePassword" name = "password changer">
          @csrf
            <br><label>input old password: <input type="password" name="oldPassword" maxlength = '16'></label>
            <br><label>input new password: <input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPassword" maxlength = '16'></label>
            <br><label>confirm new password: <input type="password" name="newPassword_confirmation" placeholder="please, confirm the password" maxlength = '16'></label>
            <br>
            <input type="submit"class="log"value="Change password">


          </form>
```

Как же сделать так, чтобы всё работало даже с моим request'ом?

Comment: `get` разрешает только get-запросы, `post` только пост. чего вы хотите-то от них? дальнейшие примеры кода смысла не имеют, потому что типы запросы фильтруются на этапе роутинга, до контроллера дело не доходит. Хотите все сразу, обратитесь к документации, найдете там про `match` и `any`

Comment: Вы же явно описали `Route::post('/personalOffice/changePassword', [ChangePasswordController::class, 'changePassword']);` - указанный URL обрабатывает указанный контроллер и только указанным методом передачи данных т.е `POST` - как и сказал г-н @teran чего Вы еще хотите? Почитайте получше документацию о роутинге `https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/routing`

Comment: @teran Понимаю я, что post - для post запросов... Но почему это "до контроллера дело не доходит", eсли у меня форма имеет method="post"?

Comment: потому что роутинг запросы фильтрует. Если у вас определен post маршрут, а вы отправляете get-запрос, то маршрутизатор не будет управление в контроллер передавать.

Comment: @phpBear Так у меня форма как раз использует метод POST... Так в чём же тогда проблема?

Comment: @teran Смотрите: у меня post-запрос, судя по тому, что в форме указано method="post", разве не так? Маршрут тоже post... Поэтому маршрутизатор всё таки должен передать управление в контроллер. Разве нет?

Comment: может все дело в `action` формы, ибо там путь относительный? вообще генерите url с  помощью `action(ChangePasswordController::class, 'changePassword')`

Comment: @teran путь я переделал на неотносительный, но ничего не изменилось...

Comment: у вас в целом должен быть один get-маршрут, который отображает форму, и второй post-маршурт, (с кастом реквестом в контроллере) который принимает от нее данные. У вас так оно и сделано?

Comment: @teran у меня только один маршрут: Route::post('/personalOffice/changePassword', [ChangePasswordController::class, 'changePassword']);
Как мне следует сделать маршрут, отображающий форму? Для всех форм  у меня всегда был лишь 1 Route...

Comment: я вам в первом комменте еще написал про match и any, мб таки попробуете?

Comment: match метод вообще не сработал... any - вёл себя так же как и post. Дело в том, что ошибка появляется лишь тогда, когда валидацию пароль не проходит... Т.е. если всё норм, то меня форма переведёт на пустую страницу, а в иных случаях - ошибка. По-идее, если валидация не пройдена, то ларавел должен оставить пользователя на той же странице и всё... Или я чего-то не знаю?)